OWLAPI + Openllet dom't see the presence of data property in individuals
I wrote rules which calculate the time of passage of a section of the route.
After executing the rules, the reasoner remembers the time as a dataProperty of an object of the RouteInformation class. However, when trying to get these values from the ontology, an empty set is returned. The values are present in the ontology (as seen in the second screenshot). There are no such problems with the rest of the rules.
Before executing of rules
After executing of rules

Please provide your minimal complete ontology in English. Please add it as code to your question.

When I translated the ontology (including the names of properties and classes), the reasoner began to find these properties. But this doesn't solve the problem that the reasoner doesn't see these properties if they are added by the rules.

I cannot follow your description. You have some rules in your ontology, then run the reasoner - that shows up the additional axioms inferred by the rules. And then, what exactly is missing afterwards? What means "getting these values from the ontology"?

I saved inferred axioms into ontology by using InferredOntologyGenerator. When I try to get data properties related to the time of the road passage from the ontology, I get an empty set. However, data properties derived from the rules for determining road safety are not returned as an empty set.

InferredOntologyGenerator might be where the problem is, can you share the code you have for using that?

@Ignazio, If you're talking about code adding inferred axioms to an ontology: reasoner.flush();
reasoner.getKB().realize();
InferredOntologyGenerator generator = new InferredOntologyGenerator(reasoner);
generator.fillOntology(factory, o);

@Ignazio. If I understood correctly, then to create axioms about dataProperties, you need to use the InferredDataPropertyAxiomGenerator. But I can't create it unlike other generators.

The problem was due to a typo in the name of the property.
